# js adding a new element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i am working on node js app, there i am facing a problem that i have to add position points in array but every position point is different like 1 st array/object need to have 10 then next array/object have to be 7

```js
let converter = [
  { name: 'team-1', killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', killPoint: 68 }
]
const pointsystem = [10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
const positionAdd = (objects) => {
  let i = 0
  const posRes = {};
  objects.forEach(({
    name,
    killPoint
  }) => {
    posRes[name] = posRes[name] || {
      name,
      positionPoint: 0,
      killPoint: 0,
    };
    posRes[name].positionPoint = pointsystem[i+1];
    posRes[name].killPoint = killPoint;
  });
  return Object.values(posRes);
};
console.log(positionAdd(converter));
```

trying with this code but its not working as wanting

output wanting from it

```js
[
  { name: 'team-1', positionPoint: 10, killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', positionPoint: 7, killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', positionPoint: 6, killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', positionPoint: 5, killPoint: 68 }
]
```

if have more team's then point should going on until 0....

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  How is the result different from what is expected?

Comment: you need to define the variable i to make it work.

Comment: [
  { name: 'team-1', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 68 }
]

Comment: The code doesn't even run, it gets an undefined variable error.

Comment: Now it doesn't get an error, but `i` never increments. So everything uses `pointSystem[1]`.

Comment: yes i just to do with the i like i++
i tryed a for loop but won't work for me

Comment: Why not just use the second argument to the `forEach()` callback function?

Comment: Did you mean to use `i++` instead of `i+1`? That will increment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` instead of appending to the result array.

Use the second argument to the callback function to get the array index, and use that to index into `pointsystem`.

Use object spread syntax to merge that into the objects from `converter`.

```js
let converter = [
  { name: 'team-1', killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', killPoint: 68 }
]
const pointsystem = [10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
const positionAdd = (objects) => objects.map((obj, i) => ({...obj, positionPoint: pointsystem[i]}));

console.log(positionAdd(converter));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will also change the original objects. I am not sure what OP's intention is:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'team-1', killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', killPoint: 68 }
],points = [10,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];
console.log(data.map((d,i)=>{
 d.positionPoint=points[i]??0;
 return d;
}));
```

Comment: This is a neat implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 to your variable i, but not implementing i after each loop. You need to increment i by 1 after each iteration.

Example:

```
posRes[name].positionPoint = pointsystem[i];
i += 1;
```

Test:

```js
let converter = [
  { name: 'team-1', killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', killPoint: 68 }
]
const pointsystem = [10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
const positionAdd = (objects) => {
  let i = 0
  const posRes = {};
  objects.forEach(({
    name,
    killPoint
  }) => {
    posRes[name] = posRes[name] || {
      name,
      positionPoint: 0,
      killPoint: 0,
    };
    posRes[name].positionPoint = pointsystem[i];
    i += 1;
    posRes[name].killPoint = killPoint;
  });
  return Object.values(posRes);
};
console.log(positionAdd(converter));
```

Comment: not working output giving
```
[
  { name: 'team-1', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 8 },
  { name: 'team-2', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 7 },
  { name: 'team-7', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 56 },
  { name: 'team-9', positionPoint: 1, killPoint: 68 }
]

```

Comment: I added a code snippet to run - The results are what you are expecting from your question.